# Colors in grayscale image

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I am loading an image using cv2 in python (jupyter lab) and trying to display a grayscale image using plt.imshow.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('my_image.jpg')
new_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(new_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.imshow(new_img)
plt.imshow(gray)
```

When the code above is run this happens:

- img is distored in colors (as expected)
- new_img has the "correct" colors
- gray is some wierd distorted colors

My question is regarding the gray image. Why does this happen and how can I change it?

Comment: Just use `grey = cv2.imread("...", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` which will be faster and take less RAM.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html. You need write ```plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')```

Answer (score 4):

You have two options. Keep using pyplot:

```
plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')
```

Or instead using the openCV's default imshow.

```
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('new_img', new_img)
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
```

Comment: I imagine OP "wierd distorted colors" is due to the `viridis` color map, so ` cmap='gray'` should solve the problem. `cv2.imshow` requires the full OCV commands (waitkey etc.) and in Jupyter is not the best option.

Comment: Ideally, I would use cv2.imshow but this does not work in Jupyterlab. I think plt.imshow(grey, cmap='gray') is the way to go. Thanks a lot.